# Linq query for EAV

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a big (4M records) table on a SQL Server with the following columns:

- Id (a record identifier);
- PropertyName (a string that represents a property name);
- PropertyValue (an integer that represent the property's value);

keep in mind that Id is not unique for this table. Basically, I'd like to write a LINQ query that retrieves Ids and all its associated PropertyName/PropertyValue pairs:

- Id
- dictionary (maybe?) PropertyName -> PropertyValue;

is this feasible in some way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if PropertyName is not unique, you cant use dictionary

Comment: PropertyName is unique for each Id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure regarding performance but you can use GroupBy to group your data by similar Ids

Something like:

```
var result =
  from x in whatever
  group x by x.Id into g
  select new { 
         Id = g.Key, 
         Data = g.ToDictionary(i => i.PropertyName, i => i.PropertyValue)
  };
```

Refer to [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) to learn more about Linq

Comment: Would a Tuple<string, int> be better than a dictionary with only one record?

Comment: usually a record has more than one PropertyName/PropertyValue pairs.